# How to configure Sublimes preferred "Open Containing Folder" tool

Tags: sublimetext3

When right-clicking a file in an opened folder in `Sublime3` I get the option to "Open Containing Folder".

But my Manjaro keeps trying to open the path with the archive manager.

How do I configure which tool will be used?
Why does Sublime try to use the Manjaro archive manager?

Answer (score 0):

Found it on the web.
https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/open-containing-folder-solved/8639

Citing a user there with the accepted answer:
"I had this problem and I believe it was a file association for directories. I changed it to dolphin. [..]"